# regexp to chop the optional tail

Tags: regex

What regex can take any of the lines below as input

```
rtsp://server/blabla/bla RTSP/1.0
rtsp://server/blabla/bla/
rtsp://server/blabla/bla
rtsp://server/blabla/bla/streamid=65335 RTSP/1.0
```

and always returns:

```
rtsp://server/blabla/bla
```

In general I have an arbitrary URL which always starts with `"rtsp://"` and optionally ends with `EOL`, `"/"`, `" RTSP/1.0"` or `"/streamid=65335 RTSP/1.0"`.

I need to get the URL only i.e. without the optional trailing parts.

Thanks.

Comment: None of the input urls contain "9C8CE56C490F2C87" so where are you getting that? I think you need to explain your question better.

Comment: Could you clarify that a little bit. What is the pattern that should be matches? Even “.*” could be used to match any of the lines.

Comment: Please, see my edited post at the top again.

Comment: 2 questions-- 1) Sometimes a trailing / is significant.  Is it possible you will need it?  2) streamid=65335 is part of the url in the last example. Will you need that?

Comment: I posted a perl regex solution, can that work, or does it need to be in another language.

Comment: @sfossen - Your Perl regex should work in most regex flavors. However, I still think using a regular expression for this is overkill.

Comment: @Chris Lutz - why is it overkill? Do Regex take more resources

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should capture the server name.

```
/rtsp:\/\/([^\/]+)/
```

from new requirements ( this removes trailing ):

```
linux ~ $ echo "rtsp://server/blabla/bla RTSP/1.0
rtsp://server/blabla/bla/
rtsp://server/blabla/bla
rtsp://server/blabla/bla/streamid=65335 RTSP/1.0
" | perl -pe 's/( RTSP\/1.0|\/|\/streamid=65335 RTSP\/1\.0)$//g'
rtsp://server/blabla/bla
rtsp://server/blabla/bla
rtsp://server/blabla/bla
rtsp://server/blabla/bla
```

This one captures url:

```
echo "rtsp://server/blabla/bla RTSP/1.0
rtsp://server/blabla/bla/
rtsp://server/blabla/bla
rtsp://server/blabla/bla/streamid=65335 RTSP/1.0
" | perl -pe 's/(.+?)(?: RTSP\/1.0|\/|\/streamid=65335 RTSP\/1\.0)$/\1/'
rtsp://server/blabla/bla
rtsp://server/blabla/bla
rtsp://server/blabla/bla
rtsp://server/blabla/bla
```

Comment: I need the whole URL, not just the server. But the URL without all the trailing part. Please, see my edited post at the top again.

Answer (score 1):

well this will do exactly what you just asked for:

```
$pattern = '/rtsp:\/\/server\/.*/'
$replace = 'server/9C8CE56C490F2C87';

preg_replace($pattern, $replace, 'rtsp://server/blabla/bla RTSP/1.0');
```

If you want to get everything before the space this will work:

```
$pattern = '/([^ ]+).*/'

preg_replace($pattern, '$1', 'rtsp://server/blabla/bla RTSP/1.0');
```

Comment: I need the whole URL. But the URL without all the trailing part. Please, see my edited post at the top again.

Answer (score 1):

You could match against:

```
(.*?)(\/streamid\=65335)?(\/)?( RTSP\/1.0)?(\n)?$
```

and read only the first group.

Depending on what language you are using it might be clearer to use string-processing. For example in Python:

```
for suffix in ('\n', ' RTSP/1.0', '/streamid=65335', '/'):
    if url.endswith(suffix):
        url= url[:-len(suffix)]
```

Comment: I agree he shouldn't look to a regex in this case, but he's using C (or C++?) for what it's worth.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your new criteria, I don't think you need a regex.

EDIT: Removed Perl solution, since you're using C. Using C, do this:

```
str[20] = 0; // string is now NUL-terminated to 20 characters
if(!strcmp(str, "rtsp://server/blabla/bla"))
  {
    // do stuff if it matches
  }
else
  {
    // do stuff if it doesn't match
  }
```

Or, if you want to keep the original string:

```
if(!strncmp(str, "rtsp://server/blabla/bla", 20)) // only compare 20 chars
  {
    // do stuff if it matches
  }
else
  {
    // do stuff if it doesn't match
  }
```

You may want to do the `strncmp()` solution. That way, you can vary the length on a query to query basis.

Comment: sorry but I'm using GNU C library regex functions

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
^rtsp://([^/]+)
```

And then replacing it by “`$1/9C8CE56C490F2C87`”?